# Kotlin serialization: Implementing a custom encoder for digest which ignore a val in an interface

Tags: kotlin, hash, kotlinx.serialization

I'm making my own implementation of AbstractEncoder for a goal of digest, trying to ignore specific interface when implementing Encoder.
I have an interface:

```
interface HasId {
    val Id: Int
}
```

and various classes implementing it:

```
@Serializable
data class A(val j: Int, override val Id: Int) : HasId 
@Serializable
data class B(val bunchOfOtherStuff : Bunch, val k: Int, override val Id: Int) : HasId
```

Those types are also serialized for other reasons that do need the Id to be included.
Given that I have an interface for indication, how can I ignore it without implementing a bunch of serializers manually?

Currently, I have tried this:

```
class MyEncoder : AbstractEncoder { ...
    override fun encodeElement(descriptor: SerialDescriptor, index: Int): Boolean {
        val elem = descriptor.getElementDescriptor(index)
        val isNeedSerialization = !(elem.kind == PrimitiveKind.INT &&     descriptor.getElementName(index) == "Id")
        if (!isNeedSerialization) {
            println("skip serializing ${elem.serialName}")
        }
        return isNeedSerialization

    }
}
```

And it works, but will fail on the class that doesn't inherit from HasId:
`data class C(val j: Int, val Id: Int)`

Thought of something like:

```
override fun <T : Any?> encodeSerializableElement(
        descriptor: SerialDescriptor,
        index: Int,
        serializer: SerializationStrategy<T>,
        value: T
    ) {
        if (value is HasId) {
            //pass a descriptor or serializer that will ignore it
        }
        else super.encodeSerializableElement(...)

    }
```